# Relationship between two objects

Tags: java, class, object

I'm working on a project for school that is challenging my understanding of OOP. I have multiple objects of the same class, City. Each City has a location.  If my understanding is correct, since the distance between each City is dependent on another City "int distance" can't be a field within the class City. I can write a method to calculate the distance between each City, but I'm not sure how/where to save that data. I would like to eventually sort this data to find which City objects are in closest proximity.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) I am afraid this question is off-topic, because it is not about a specific problem you encountered when trying to write a solution. Feel free to ask another, more specific question when you encounter a problem (for example when the distance calculation doesn't work)

Comment: you could use a method on one city which accepts the second city as a parameter.  int distanceBetween(City otherCity) - but you wouldn't save that anywhere. you would just return that from the method. if you needed to save these distances you could make a new class which represented this. Maybe a Distance class which contains references to two Cities, and the distance calculated

Comment: Nevertheless, I don't like sending people away without helping. I recommend to store the position of each city inside the city class and in another, superior class store the cities and a twodimensional array that contains the distances.

Comment: It is understandable that you can't think of a way to save this data in a `City`, because conceptually there's no such thing as a City's 'distance'. You want to talk about the distance between two cities, so perhaps you need another concept (implemented as another class)?

Comment: It's all about how you define your data model.  If you have some kind of global coordinate system then each city would have its own coordinates.  It would be straightforward, then, to have a method to calculate the distance between any two city objects that are passed as arguments to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a `Map` class (as in cartography, not the usual `Collection`), whose instances would contain a `Set` of `Cities`. They could provide method to calculate additional information about the relations between their `Cities`, and cache the result if needed.

It is not necessary that the `Map` contains the `Cities` but it sounds logical and will surely help manipulating them. If you don't want that you could use a "helper class", something like `DistancesHelper`, defining static methods to work on `Cities` that could interact with a static cache.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that calculation of distance should be a method of `Location` not a method of `City`. You could later decide your map has other points of interest besides cities which also have a location.

So my suggestion of structure would be:

```
interface PointOfInterest {
    Location getLocation();
    default int distanceTo(PointOfInterest other) {
        return getLocation().distanceTo(other.getLocation());
    }
}

class City implements PointOfInterest {
    private final Location location;
    @Override public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}

class Location {
    public int distanceTo(Location other) {
        ...
    }
}
```

That way any data required to define location (e.g. latitude, longitude) is completely contained within the `Location` object.